# Crystal Reports XI - Only show Details lines ending in 'C'

Tags: crystal-reports

Hopefully a straight forwards question.

I have a Report that runs from a stock system, it prints to show all the products in a customers order, as well as a general 'Thank you for your order..' message.

In the details section it currently shows Product and Product Description for everything within that order.

I have a new client though who wants another version of this report, one which only shows the details lines where the Product Code ends in the letter 'C'.

I'm guessing I need to suppress the details section but I'm not sure what Formula I should be using.
I also can't say for certain that all their product codes will remain the same length.  I think about 95% of them will be 8 characters, but any 'special edition' versions may have extra characters in.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: are you want to create new report or old one change.

Answer (score 0):

right(trim({ProductCode})) <> 'C'

Comment: I think you need to edit your formula, because it you don't mention any boolean value, it takes as true hence supress when code is `C` which is not the requirement... you need to specifically mention that if code is `C` then false else true

Comment: you are right i did slightly miss the requirement. My apologies.. edited

Answer (score 0):

A suppression formula needs to return a Boolean value, so a formula checking the last character in your Product Code field should do it:

```
right(trim({ProductCode}),1) = 'C'
```

To make it work for a single client, you could do something like this (warning: I'm rusty with Crystal syntax - take it with a grain of salt):

```
IF {CustomerCode} = 123
  THEN right(trim({ProductCode}),1) = 'C'
  ELSE false
```